Why ASTC texture format is not available in runtime?
The problem is that I cant create a Texture2D with RGBA_ASTC6X6_UNorm graphics format.
As I understand, ASTC is a special kind of compression, that could be used by GPU. In my application I can observe, that ASTC textures takes much less memory, then textures I load from PNG files. And I wonder to compress these loaded textures with ASTC also. But looks like it is not possible in the runtime.
Do I understand ASTC correctly?
Why compression is not possible during runtime? Do it have some special hardware restrictions? Which restrictions? Why I never met these restrictions during build on different devices?

Your understanding is correct, but you spelled all the ASTC incorrectly.
Image compression is possible at runtime by calling Texture2D.Compress, while the method is implemented with the graphics API, so it is limited to specific formats.
For those unsupported formats, there are no hardware restrictions, but you need to provide corresponding compression code, which can make the runtime very large.
